# DataGridComboBoxColumn not updating ItemsSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have this column:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Master" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding MasterId}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Masters, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
```

The property on the ViewModel is:

```
public ObservableCollection<ReaderViewModel> Masters { get; set; }
```

The DataGrid DataSource has a self-relationship Master-Slaves and I update the collection on any Insert/Update/Delete but the ComboBox keeps the initial values and not updates itself.

What am I doing wrong?

For the property changing I'm using the Fody addon.
If you need more code to understand the problem I'm ready to share more.

EDIT 1:

The BindingProxy class:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(DataProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DataProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

This class can be found on Google, where I found it.

EDIT 2:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <classes:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

How the BindingProxy is used.

Comment: I didn't understand if the comboboxcolumn doesn't have any value (the binding doesn't work) or when you set a value on the combo your viewmodel doesn't affect any change.

Comment: The ComboBox Items source is a subset of the DataGrid source, but when I edit a DataGrid item (create, edit or delete) that should be in the subset It doesn't appear. The ComboBox binding works fine.

Comment: Ok, and so, the ItemSource of the combobox isn't notified when something has been modified. Did you try setting mode to "OneWay"?

Comment: Yes, I tried all modes but nothing changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Master" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding MasterId}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Masters, Source={StaticResource proxy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}" />
```

**UPDATE:**

```
private ObservableCollection<ReaderViewModel> masters;
public ObservableCollection<ReaderViewModel> Masters
{ 
    get
    {
        return masters;
    }
    set
    {
        masters = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Masters");
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged(this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Master" Binding="{Binding Name}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding MasterId}" SelectedValuePath="Id" ItemsSource="{Binding Masters, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.Resources>
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.Resources>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: And: Your Class with your ObservableCollection have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface in this way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx - but I don't know, if Fody adds it automatically at compiling.

Comment: Besides the incorrect syntax (wrongly placed curly brace), it *never* makes sense to set Mode=TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the Binding of the ItemsSource property.

Comment: The Fody addon add that code where needed, as far as I know, the UpdateSourceTrigger didn't worked. The ItemsSource is still not updated

Comment: @Clemens I always use it in that way and there are no problems with. The problem I see here is that you want to use a static resource on an instance object.

Comment: "I always use it in that way and there are no problems with". Maybe you do, but it simply has no effect. An ItemsControl never sets its ItemsSource property, so there is no trigger from target to source.

Comment: @c0d3b34n the Masters collection is in the UserControl ViewModel, not in the row's. I've searched a lot and there are two solution for achieving this, the DataGridComboBoxColumnStyle one and the BindingProxy. I preferred the last one for the compact syntax.

Comment: You have to use x:Static markup extension to bind to static properties. Also note that static properties binds one time. If you change the instance at runtime that won't be reflected back on UI. In your case you are dealing with ObservableCollection so when you add/delete item from collection it will be refreshed on UI. In case you want to update UI, you have to raise StaticPropertyChangedEvent.

Comment: It's not a static property as you can see in the question. The BindingProxy has a Data property for bind to the UserControl's ViewModel.

Comment: Source={StaticResource proxy} is not static?

Comment: The STATICresource proxy is (as I guess(!) of your xaml code) pointing to an instance of BindingProxy and by binding Path to Data.Masters, you are asking to bind to an instance property Data.Masters. That's why it's not working.

Comment: Your ObservableCollection calls PropertyChanged by Fody? I wouldn't use third party elements. I will edit my answer as I would do it.

Comment: I think so, It adds code while building and I can't see, but I catch the CollectionChanged events, the DataGrid and the ComboBox collections, and raise the PropertyChanged

Comment: The xaml gives me error on: DataGridComboBoxColumn.Resources, it says not found. And I think the {Binding} is related to row's ViewModel and not to the UserControl's ViewModel.

Comment: Move the Resource to the grid, like you did before. <DataGrid.Resources>
    <classes:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>

Comment: Why have an OC if you're switching out the collection?  If the property implements INPC, make it an IEnumerable<T>.  If you're not switching out the collection but are altering it, then make the collection property read only.